# iOS - CLLocationCoordinate2D/floats/long into a NSDictionary for JSON?

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm looking to convert a simple objectiveC class (not even that at the minute its just some vars in a function) to JSON so that it can be sent and impretated into a java object at the server side.

The Class might have the following fields;

```
LatLng locationA // a simple POJO with either float or long to represent lat and long. 
LatLng locationA
float someFloat
```

It the minute I am tring to pack everything in to a NSDictonary. Passing the floats in didn't work so I has to convert them to NSStrings. So on the server side they would arive as strings.. which isnt ideal.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = ... ;
float lat = location.latitude;
float lng = location.longitude;

float aFloat = 0.12434f;
NSString *aFloatstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", aFloat];

NSString *latStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lat];
NSString *lngStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lng];

NSDictionary *locationDictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        latStr , @"latitude",
        lngStr, @"longitude",
        nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                locationDictionary, @"locationA",
                                locationDictionary, @"locationB",
                                aFloatstr,@"aFloat",
                                nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Whats the best way do putting CLLocationCoordinate2Ds into an NSDictionary?

How do I add primitative types, long floats ect.. to an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of putting the latitude and longitude into `NSString`, you'll have better luck with `NSNumber`. When `NSJSONSerialization` comes upon an `NSNumber` it won't quote the value like it would a string (which is what you want when transmitting numbers, right?).

You'll also want to use `double`, not `float`, for latitude and longitude, since that's how they're represented internally. No need to throw away precision.

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat]
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lng]
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aFloat]
```

Since instances of `NSNumber` are objects, you'll be able to store them in `NSDictionary` no problem.

Comment: Thank you sartak. :)  .. I think I will be converting them to long as thats what my server and database are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNumber` instead of strings to wrap the `float` values, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *locationDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lat] , @"latitude",
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lng], @"longitude", nil];
```

That way, `NSJSONSerialization` will correctly encode them as numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

### Structs

Neat way of doing this is to create category for NSValue that understands your struct. In your case it's `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, but could be any really. Here is snippet from Apple's own documentation explaning usage of `NSValue`:

```
// NSValue+Polyhedron.h
typedef struct {
    int numFaces;
    float radius;
} Polyhedron;

@interface NSValue (Polyhedron)
+ (instancetype)valueWithPolyhedron:(Polyhedron)value;
@property (readonly) Polyhedron polyhedronValue;
@end


// NSValue+Polyhedron.m
@implementation NSValue (Polyhedron)
+ (instancetype)valueWithPolyhedron:(Polyhedron)value
{
    return [self valueWithBytes:&value objCType:@encode(Polyhedron)];
}
- (Polyhedron) polyhedronValue
{
    Polyhedron value;
    [self getValue:&value];
    return value;
}
@end
```

From here usage is quite trivial. To create boxed NSValue:

```
NSValue *boxedPolyhedron = [NSValue valueWithPolyhedron:yourStruct];
```

Now you can put `boxedPolyhedron` whenever `NSValue` can go, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`, and many more, plus al the mutable versions.

To get struct back:

```
Polyhedron polyStruct = [boxedPolyhedron polyhedronValue];
```

That's it.

As a bonus, this works for *any C type*, not only for structs.

## floats, longs, etc.

As mentioned above, could do same as above. But, for numbers, you could use `NSNumber` which is actually a subclass if `NSValue` with all popular methods already implemented. Here is a list of types you can box by instantiating `NSNumber`:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithChar:(char)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedChar:(unsigned char)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithShort:(short)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedShort:(unsigned short)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithLong:(long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLong:(unsigned long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithLongLong:(long long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(unsigned long long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithFloat:(float)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithDouble:(double)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)value;
```

In similiar fashion you un-box values using `[yourNumber longValue]`, `[yourNumber floatValue]`, etc.

Hope that helps.